# Erro de tradução: votado contra / votar contra

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Na página de reputação o texto de quando recebo um downvote está estranho:

[image: erro tradução]

- `votado contra` é quando eu dou um downvote. Este aqui parece bom.
- `votar contra` é quando eu recebo um downvote. Este está estranho, acho que talvez pudesse ser alterado para `votaram contra`.

Comment: Ou, se quisermos seguir o estilo do SO, ambos poderiam ser "voto contra".

Comment: Acabei de fazer as edições, que ficaram de acordo com a minha resposta, e não a do @LeandroAmorim, pelos motivos que estão no [meu comentário](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131/erro-de-traducao-votado-contra-votar-contra#comment2342_839)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu sugiro:

`voto contra/a favor` quando você **recebe** voto

`votou contra` quando você **dá** um downvote

Comment: Eu não acho que o "votou" deixe claro quem votou... Pode ser "você" ou "ele" (os portugueses não têm esse problema).

Comment: @bfavaretto "votado contra" então?

Comment: Sei não, Gabe. Eu prefiro "voto contra" nos dois casos mesmo (e a pontuação indica a direção do voto).

Comment: concordo com o @bfavaretto, eu falo português de Portugal e acho melhor "voto contra" para os dois, à semelhança do SOen, onde só há uma palavra. Eventualmente poderia ser "voto positivo / voto negativo".

Comment: @Sergio O SO não usa a mesma palavra para os dois. usa "downvote" e "downvoted". Usar o mesmo para os dois é bastante confuso, principalmente se você não está familiarizado com as regras do site.

Comment: @Gabe, hmm verdade. Não tinha reparado, talvez porque eu ligo mais à pontuação. Nesse caso, se a ideia é diferenciar os dois, eu _voto a favor_

Comment: @Sergio Eu tive que ir procurar antes de sugerir, também... `downvoted` é usado quando você **dá** o voto

Comment: Verdade, Gabe, eu me confundi em relação ao SO. Mesmo lá é confuso... Acho que independentemente da decisão vai ter gente perguntando sobre isso aqui no meta!

Comment: @bfavaretto Provavelmente... É uma idéia difícil de passar com uma ou duas palavras...

Comment: Acho que poderia ficar `voto contra` e `votaram contra`. Nem que seja temporariamente, ficaria melhor do que o modo atual...

Comment: Não pode ter 3 palavras? `Voto contra dado` e `Voto contra recebido`.

Comment: Acho que a sugestão do Leandro - votaram e votei - mata a questão.

Answer (score 5):

> **Votaram contra/a favor** quando você recebe voto

É melhor usar o sujeito indeterminado (3ª pessoa do plural) visto que você não sabe quem votou, Usando **"[Eles] Votaram"** no lugar de **"[Alguém] Votou"** fica mais óbvio.

> **Votei contra/a favor** quando você dá um voto

Aqui fica claro que foi Eu (sujeito está oculto) quem proferi o voto.

Comment: Infelizmente não foi possível fazer dessa maneira. Os termos `upvote` e `downvote` são utilizados da mesma forma na sua página de votos (1a pessoa) e na de reputação (3a pessoa), então não havia como fazer a distinção.